# Filter 'rxjs' Observable and render filtered object in my component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to filter observable objects by the id, but getting error. I have already get some dummy data from json file but have no clue how to display that object into a solid form. Any help?

**Service.ts**:

```typescript
export class ProjectService {
  private pathurl : string = "/assets/project-data.json";
  constructor (private http: HttpClient){} 

  getProjects(): Observable<ProjectInt[]>{return this.http.get<ProjectInt[]>(this.pathurl)};
```

**Component.ts** file:

```typescript
filterProj(){
    var filteredProj = this.projectService.getProjects() 
      .pipe
        (map(projects => this.projects.filter(project => project.id < 3))
       );

return filteredProj;
}
```

**Components.html**:

```html
<a class="button" (click)="filterProj()"><span>DESIGN</span></a>
```

Comment: What is the structure of json?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of issues:

1. You need to subscribe to the observable to actually get data from
   it:

   ```
   data;

   filterProj(){
     this.projectService.getProjects() 
        .pipe
          (map(projects => this.projects.filter(project => project.id < 3))
         )
        .subscribe(response => this.data = response);        
   }
   ```
2. Store the response from the observable in a variable, for eg:
   `data`. Now you can use this in your template:

   ```
   <div *ngIf="data">
      {{ data | json}}
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Thanks Fella, I already solve this problem And you give me a huge hint. So, I have several filtered options by id (like Id < 3, Id > 3 && id < 5 and so on.) But when i am trying to filter again the subscribe method gives me already filtered data. How can i  initially point previous Observable to have initial set of data? I mean kind of Reset of default set

Comment: Do accept the answer in that case! I didn't get your second question, could you clarify it?

Comment: I'd like to filter data by the different filter methods. I want to have initial set (not filtered one) again to filter by different methods.
  `filterProjLessThenThree(){

  this.projectService.getProjects()
  .pipe(
  map(projects => this.projects.filter(project => project.id > 5)))
  .subscribe(response => this.projects = response);


  }`

  `filterProjBeetwenThreeAndFive(){

    this.projectService.getProjects()
    .pipe(
    map(projects => this.projects.filter(project => project.id >= 3 && project.id < 5)))
    .subscribe(response => this.projects = response);


  }`

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the filtered list from the `map` operator.

```
filterProj() {
  this.projectService.getProjects().pipe(
    map(projects => {
      const filteredList = projects.filter(project => project.id < 3);
      return filteredList;
    })
  );
}
```

Or you could use the `filter` operator.

```
filterProj() {
  this.projectService.getProjects().pipe(
    filter(project => project.id < 3)
  );
}
```

Update:
I missed the subscription part. As @Nicholas K suggested in his answer, you need to subscribe to your observable to get the value of it.

One suggestion: `filter` operator is more readable than `map` operator when you need to filter data.